# Our AZURE seems to not be replicating successful changes

Tags: entra-id

We recently added a new server (04JHB-SRV01 with IP Address – 10.10.10.20) to our domain.
I have transferred FSMO roles and AD Users and groups to it.
DNS is still running on it but not DHCP.
Our AZURE seems to not be replicating successful changes.

I suspect that the AD Connect (Dirsync) server may not see the new DC. Or possibly that the dirsync server has encountered an error and needs to be reset up

Comment: It's not clear what you're talking about. You mentioned Azure so I'll assume you mean that you're syncing your on premises AD to Azure. You also mention DirSync. DirSync has been deprecated. You should replace DirSync with Azure AD Connect. Also, when you say successful changes won't replicate exactly what do you mean? Give us as much detail as possible on the problem and your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

First - if you really are running DirSync, that's the reason.  It's no longer supported and Microsoft has stopped allowing sync from it.  you need to be running AzureAD Connect.

Assuming you are running AzureAD Connect and still have problems.  Check the sync jobs first - the errors there usually tell you what the problem is.  Also, check Azure and the AD Connect Health dashboard - see what's reported for the server.

Some things that it could be:

AzureAD connect can be configured to talk to specific domain controllers.  It's not typical, but if the connector was modified it could be the case.

You've modified the service account (changed pw, disabled, etc).  This would prevent it from talking to AD to get user changes.

Make sure your NSG's are not blocking ports between the connect server and the DC.  You need 53,88,135,389,445,636,49152-65535 between them.  If you restrict ports, it wont be able to talk to AD and get user information.

Make sure NSG's are not blocking outbound connections to port 80 and 443 from sync server.